# Niveau d'orthographe

Tags: orthographe, écriture

Quelles sont quelques fautes d'écriture  intolérables qui indiquent un niveau d'acquisition de l'orthographe du français insuffisant ?

Par exemple, dans un texto reçu, un ami locuteur natif a écrit :

> ...**C'est** parents travaillent.

Je trouve de telles erreurs insupportables.

En outre, j'ai reçu un email comportant le texte ci-dessous : " N'ayant pas reçu de réponse je me permet de vous renvoyer le mail pour vous prévenir et discuter avec vous du fait que je ne pourrai pas être présent à la khôlle de Maths de ce mercredi car je suis un cas contact et donc je suis confiné. Je voulais donc savoir si il était possible de réaliser la khôlle en visio?" [kholle c'est ça : fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/… (Argot scolaire) Interrogation orale, individuelle ou collective, s’inscrivant dans le cursus des classes préparatoires aux grandes écoles, d’une durée d’une heure en général.]

Sont-elles les fautes que j'ai mentionnées normales pour un locuteur natif/une locutrice native ("je me permet" au lieu de "je me permets" ; "je voulais" au lieu de je voudrais et si il était au lieu de s'il était) ?

Dans le même esprit, quelles sont quelques fautes de l'orthographe qui pourraient être considérées comme tolérables pour une personne qui a fini ses études après le secondaire ?

Comment: Déjà par sms tu as le correcteur de texte, ça peut donc être une erreur du téléphone et non de lui. Sinon les petites erreurs comme les oublies de 's' au pluriel sont assez acceptées. Et après tout dépend du contexte. Dans un contexte professionnel c'est une tolérance zéro. Dans un contexte informel tout est plus ou moins accepté.

Comment: Je ne pense pas que l'on puisse avoir une réponse générale à cette question. Cela dépendra de la sensibilité des gens (et probablement du milieu).

Comment: @LPH **C'est** parents est la faute. J'ai écrit toute sa réponse.

Comment: Certaines erreurs sur les doubles consonnes (fautes d'usage) sont « acceptables » selon le contexte. Les fautes de grammaire ne le sont jamais.

Comment: A noter que l'excuse du correcteur sur ce type de faute est relativement peu crédible, de manière générale le correcteur automatique ne changera pas un pronom possessif en un pronom + verbe et encore moins si la première lettre diffère. J'écris avec un Qwerty (même en français et je n'ai jamais ce type de corrections, sur android / clavier google).

Comment: An interesting inversion of my last question. Yeah, English speakers often spell their language poorly but French speakers take the gold home in the homophone category. Some favourites I collected this past spring while marking a Francophone literacy test (pardon me if I shared them somewhere already): foll-rit, appro peau, j'ainer [gêner], n'ont [=non], vremand, dession [décision], esseiller, daijas, ce l'on moi, plaitsire, je les emai mes ces tes pas pour moi. « Tolérable » ? J'en sais rien. Fréquent ? Bien sûr ...

Comment: @LukeSawczak I think you should give your comment as an answer (a hilarious one by the way:-)!).

Comment: @LukeSawczak Some of your examples (foll-rit!, appro peau! j'ainer! vremand! dession!,  esseiller! daijas! ce l'on moi, plaitsire!) are extraordinary but "je les emai mes ces tes pas pour moi" blows every example cited here out of water:-)!

Comment: @LukeSawczak C'est quoi _foll-rit_ ? Follerie... _madness_ ?

Comment: @suiiurisesse Oui — les folleries du théâtre, si je me rappelle bien... Dimitris : Merci. Je trouve que mes exemples ne répondent pas vraiment à ta question (étant loin d'être « tolérables »), mais je suis content que tu les apprécies ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Les erreurs que je trouve les plus insupportables sont (liste non exhaustive):

- Il a manger (un classique)
- Il ses trompé (Il s'est trompé)
- Ces pas mon problème
- Il sait trompé (.............)
- Comme même (quand même)
- Salut sa va (un autre grand classique)
- Il et content (il est...)
- Tu est méchant

Il en existe évidemment beaucoup d'autres.

(edit, j'en ajoute quelques uns)

- Qu'elle erreur
- J'ai était
- Je m'ai trompé

Answer (score 2):

Je ne sais pas si on peut vraiment parler de fautes d'orthographe dans les cas qui sont décrits plus haut.

*Insupportable* transcrit *insuportable* (le correcteur d'orthographe me rajoute les deux *p*) est à proprement parler une faute d'orthographe.

*C'est parents* (aucune intervention du correcteur automatique) pour *ses parents* révèle la confusion que génèrent les homophones. /se/ peut renvoyer à *c'est*, *ses*, *ces*, *sait*, *sais*, *Sée* et j'en oublie certainement.  /vɛʀ/ à *vers*, *vert*, *ver*, *verre*…  Ce sont typiquement des fautes qu'un étranger ne commet pas vu que tous ces mots sont clairement distingués dans sa langue.  Par exemple /vɛr/ pour un Italien renverra à *verso*, *verde*, *verme*, *vetro* ou *bicchiere*.

On insiste dans l'enseignement de la langue écrite sur les distinctions à faire et à maintenir entre les homophones. Les petits Italiens s'entendront répéter qu'il ne faut pas confondre *ho* et *o*, les petits Français *a*, *as* et *à*, *ou* et *où*, les petits Anglais *his* et *he's*, *their* et *there*.

Ces erreurs indiquent un niveau de scolarisation peu élevé et sont stigmatisées à cause de ça. Pour ce qui est de l'acquisition de la langue maternelle, elle se fait parfaitement sans qu'il soit nécessaire d'avoir une bonne orthographe, sans qu'il soit même nécessaire de savoir écrire.

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'accord sur le fait de qualifier d'homophone *c'est* et *ses*, la prononciation n'est clairement pas la même ! De plus l'auteur du post parlait bien d'un locuteur natif et non pas d'une personne n'ayant pas le français comme langue natale.

Comment: Cette question d'homophones et des difficultés qu'ils posent concerne bien les locuteurs natifs, nous sommes d'accord. Quant /ɛ/ et /e/, pour moi, ils sont en distribution complémentaire, /ɛ/ en syllabe fermée, /e/ en syllabe ouverte, de sorte que "c'est" et "ses", mais aussi "lait" et "les" se prononcent de manière identique dans mon cas. Je ne prétends pas que cela vaille pour tous les francophones.

Comment: Disons que dans ton cas c'est un homophone mais pour la majorité de ceux qui font ces erreurs ce n'est pas le cas. Le *comme même* en est l'exemple parfait, je doute que quelque part en France (ou à l'étranger) l'on prononce *comme* = *quand*.

Answer (score 1):

**I** C'est une faute intolérable ; elle est intolérable comme elle montre un niveau de compréhension qui peut être reconnu comme celui des cours élémentaires de l'école primaire. S'il ne s'agit pas d'un manque de compréhension et que c'est le fait d'écrire plutôt machinalement on doit conclure que l'étourderie que cela dénonce est extrême, et alors on pourrait avoir peut être plus de tolérance, mais c'est une limite.

Des fautes similaires et intolérables

- été ↔ était
- du ↔ de l'
- de ↔ des

**II** Les fautes que l'on peut trouver tolérables sont d'abord de la sorte que l'on trouve ci-dessous (étourderie); elles sont tolérables seulement à condition qu'elles ne soient pas répétées,  c'est à dire à condition qu'elles ne soient  pas une habitude chez celui qui écrit ; on peut les tolérer parce que l'on soupçonne qu'elles ne résultent pas d'un manque de compréhension ni  d'une attitude de totale indifférence mais d'une préoccupation avec la teneur du texte et que le travail machinal de transcription des mots est en faute, le son guidant la frappe de façon erratique. On peut les considérer comme de l'étourderie légère.

- ce ↔ se
- ces ↔ ses
- c'est ↔ s'est
- sa ↔ ça
- les oublis des s des pluriels
- les oublis des s et e dans les accord des participes passés
- lettres doublée ↔  lettre non doublée (dans certains cas)

…

**III** On peut ensuite tolérer certaine fautes dues au manque de connaissances avancées de la langue ;

- élision : lorsqu' il ↔ lorsque il, tandis qu'avant ↔ tandis que avant, …
- accords pointilleux de participes passé : Des femmes, il en a salué toute la journée ↔ Des femmes, il en a saluées toute la journée

(*évidemment, cela n'est qu'un très maigre échantillon.*)